# I want to activate my sensor when a continuous noise sounds ( Android Studio )

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am learning to program and the truth is that I don't have much idea. I am programming an application that consists of an audio sensor and when a noise is heard in the house it is activated. I currently have this code.

Activity DetectNoise

```
public class DetectNoise {




   // This file is used to record voice
   static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

   private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
   private double mEMA = 0.0;

   public void start() {



       if (mRecorder == null) {


           mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
           mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

           try {
               mRecorder.prepare();
               mRecorder.start();
               mEMA = 0.0;
           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
               Log.e("Error",e.toString());
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               Log.e("Error",e.toString());
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
   }



public double getAmplitude() {



       if (mRecorder != null)
           //return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/1100.0);


           return   20 * Math.log10(mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() / 2000);
       else
           return 0;

   }

public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
       double amp = getAmplitude();
       mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
       return mEMA;
   }
```

Activity One

```
private int mThreshold;
private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 300;
mSensor = new DetectNoise();
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mPollTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

               double amp = mSensor.getAmplitude();
               //Log.i("Noise", "runnable mPollTask");
               updateDisplay("Monitoring Voice...", amp);

               if ((amp > mThreshold)) {
                   callForHelp(amp);
                   //Log.i("Noise", "==== onCreate ===");
               }// Runnable(mPollTask) will again execute after POLL_INTERVAL
               mHandler.postDelayed(mPollTask, POLL_INTERVAL); }
```

The problem is that with any sound it is activated. I want it to activate only when the sound lasts about 5 or 7 seconds continued.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you so much for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start init time stamp is null, you can get from the first amplitude to record time stamp,  if they are sound in the detection process disappear,you can reset time stamp to null, If the sound persists then the first recorded time stamp will be kept.You only need to determine the time stamp and time stamp records are obtained subtraction judge the sound duration

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, but I don't understand your answer, I have been programming for a short time, and I am a bad programmer. By example it is easier to understand

Comment: Please post everything in one answer. Don't give answers multiple times for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
        
/**
 *  Sorry for my poor english
 */
import java.util.Random;
public class Test implements Runnable {
    //You can try start
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Test()).start();
    }
    private static Long lastTime = null;
    @Override
    public void run() {
//      This is a cycle monitor the recording volume
        while (true) {
            char temp = getAmplitude();
            System.out.print(temp);//test output
            try {
//              Sound is detected for the first time
                if (lastTime == null && temp!='_')
                    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//              Stopped sound detected
                if (temp=='_')
                    lastTime=null;

//              Sound keeps coming
//              Judgment time interval
                if(lastTime != null && System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTime>=2*1000){
//                  Speak more than two seconds
                    System.out.println("---|>Speak more than two seconds");
                    lastTime=null;
                }
//              A sampling rate of 100 ms
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
    // Analog recording volume
    private static char getAmplitude() {
        // If there is sound output 'A'  , No sound output '_'
        // You can determine whether there is sound by the sound level
        // This is an example
        if (new Random().nextInt(100) <=7)
            return '_';//无声音
        return 'A';//有声音
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
}
```